# Get method/function/variable name as String in Scala

Tags: scala, literals

In Java, I can do `TheClass.class.getName()` to get to a class name that I need as a String somewhere (avoiding to type it again, avoiding typos, clearly documenting dependencies).

Can I do the same for a function (or other things) in Scala ?

```
val theName : String = nameOf[aFunctionThatICanSeeHere]
```

Comment: Actually inside the brackets scala awaits type parameter, how do you expect to identify function by its type?

Answer (score 3):

For a class name:

```
val theName = classOf[TheClass].getName
```

`classOf[TheClass]` is the same as `TheClass.class` in Java.

For names of methods etc. you could use [reflection](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html), just like in Java. (Note that the Scala reflection API is currently still experimental).

*edit* - Scala is, besides an object-oriented programming language, also a functional programming language. You can pass functions as values. For example:

```
class Thing {
  def method(x: Int): Int = x + 2
}

val thing = new Thing

// fn is a value that refers to a method
// similar to (but not really the same as) a method reference in Java
val fn = thing.method _

// you can call the method through fn
val result = fn(3) // same as thing.method(3)
```

Comment: I think, *experimental* tag means that current reflection lib is heavily based on compiler internals and is a subject to change with possible change of compiler implementation.

Comment: Do you have an example for using reflection to get a method name?

Comment: See [Inspecting a Runtime Type](http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) which shows how to, among other things, inspect a type and find the methods on it.

Comment: Can't seem to find anything in there that would let me get to a method name from a reference to it (like `classOf[TheClass]` does it). All examples have the name of the method specified as a String. I want the opposite: Get to that String (the method name), from some kind of literal/symbol in source code.

Comment: I guess the question is "Is there a Scala equivalent to a Java 8 method reference like `ClassName::methodName` ?")

Comment: But a Java method reference does not get you the method name as a **string**, so that was not clear from your original question. Scala is a functional language so you can use functions as values. If you want a method as a function you can do: `val fn = methodName _`. See my edit above

Answer (score 2):

You can use [scala-nameof](https://github.com/dwickern/scala-nameof) to get a function name, variable name, class member name, or type name. It happens at compile-time so there's no reflection involved and no runtime dependency needed.

```
val theName = nameOf(aFunctionThatICanSeeHere _)
```

will compile to:

```
val theName = "aFunctionThatICanSeeHere"
```

Answer (score 1):

This uses the [ObjectWeb ASM](http://asm.ow2.org/) library. This extracts all the methods of a given class instance. There is also code for getting method name inside this.

```
import org.objectweb.asm.Type
import org.objectweb.asm.Type
import org.objectweb.asm.tree._
import org.objectweb.asm.util._
import java.lang.reflect.Method


case class ScalaMethod(name:String, returnType:Type, params:List[Param], parentClassName:String)
case class Param(paraName:String, paraType:Type)
object MethodReader {
  /*
   * stackoverflow.com/questions/7640617/how-to-get-parameter-names-and-types-via-reflection-in-scala-java-methods
   */
  def getMethods(c:AnyRef, is:java.io.InputStream) = {
    val cn = new ClassNode();
    val cr = new ClassReader(is);
    cr.accept(cn, 0);
    is.close();
    val methods = cn.methods.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[MethodNode]];
    var mList:List[ScalaMethod] = Nil
    if (methods.size > 0) for (i <- 1 to methods.size) {
      try {
        val m:MethodNode = methods.get(i-1)
        val argTypes:Array[Type] = Type.getArgumentTypes(m.desc);
        val vars = m.localVariables.asInstanceOf[java.util.List[LocalVariableNode]];
        var pList:List[Param] = Nil
        if (argTypes.length > 0 && vars.length > 0) for (i <- 1 to argTypes.length) {
          // The first local variable actually represents the "this" object in some cases
          val difference = if (vars.get(0).name == "this") 0 else 1
          pList = Param(vars.get(i-difference).name, argTypes(i-1)) :: pList
        }
        mList = ScalaMethod(m.name, Type.getReturnType(m.desc), pList.reverse, c.getClass.getCanonicalName):: mList
      } catch { 
        case e:Throwable => 
      }
    }
    mList.reverse
  }
  def getMethods(c, is):List[ScalaMethod] = {
    val t = Type.getType(c);
    val url = t.getInternalName() + ".class";
    val is = try {
      val cl = c.getClassLoader();
      val is = cl.getResourceAsStream(url);
      if (is == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot find class: " + url);
      else is
    } catch {
      case e:IllegalArgumentException => 
        new java.io.FileInputStream(url)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hmm. So how do I use this to find the name of the given method?

Comment: The line `mList = ScalaMethod(m.name, Type.getReturnType(m.desc), pList.reverse, c.getClass.getCanonicalName):: mList` gets the method name. The code also gives additional information (such as method parameters) in case you need it.